# Action do form não encontrada Not Found!

Tags: php, ajax, mvc

Estou com um projeto em PHP utilizando MVC, certo... foi criado um formulário para cadastros que seria enviado por jQuery Ajax, porem na hora de setar a url para qual o form seria enviado ele não encontra o Controller desejado para executar o submit aparece um erro NOT Found url. tenho o projeto no github..

https://github.com/wDrik/Dkse

```
url:"/App/Controllers/RegisterController.php",
```

já tentei assim e de varias outras formas, porem nenhuma deu certo..

**Quem puder me ajudar agradeço.**

Answer (score 0):

O nome no arquivo esta invertido na pergunta ControllerRegister.php quando no projeto está RegisterController.php, não sei se é só isso mas corrige ai!

Comment: foi um erro de digitação e o mesmo já foi corrigido porem não resolveu meu problema...